# Increase plot size in shiny when using ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Is there a way to increase the plot window size in `shiny` dependent on the number of facets that are used in a `ggplot` figure - perhaps using a vertical scroll.

For example, using the example below, when the input is `"A"` there are three facets and the plots look good. When the option `"B"` is selected the number of plots increases but the plot window stays the same size resulting in plots that are too small.

Is there a strategy to keep all the panel heights the same, independent of input? Thanks.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

mtcars$cyl = sample(letters[1:5], 32, TRUE)

 ui <- fluidPage(
         navbarPage(title="title",
           tabPanel("One", 
                    column(3, 
                           wellPanel( selectInput('name', 'NAME', c("A", "B")))),
                    column(9, plotOutput('plot1')))
   ))


server <- function(input, output) {

    X = reactive({input$name == "A"})

        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

          if(X()){
             p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( . ~ gear )
          }else{
            p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( cyl  ~ gear )
          }
          return(p1)})
    }



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find a working example below :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


mtcars$cyl = sample(letters[1:5], 32, TRUE)

gg_facet_nrow<- function(p){
  p %>% ggplot2::ggplot_build()  %>%
  magrittr::extract2('layout')       %>%
  magrittr::extract2('panel_layout') %>%
  magrittr::extract2('ROW')          %>%
  unique()                           %>%
  length()
  }

ui <- fluidPage(
 navbarPage(title="title",
         tabPanel("One", 
                  column(3, 
                         wellPanel( selectInput('name', 'NAME', c("A", "B")))),
                  column(9, plotOutput('plot1')))
))


server <- function(input, output) {

 X <- reactive({input$name == "A"})

 p1 <- reactive({
  if(X()){
   p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( . ~ gear )
  }else{
   p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + facet_grid( cyl  ~ gear )
  } 
 return(p1)
 })

he <- reactive(gg_facet_nrow(p1()))

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({p1() }, height = function(){he()*300})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This answer was possible thanks to the following posts :

- [Shiny : variable height of renderplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792998/shiny-variable-height-of-renderplot) (`height = function(){he()*300})`)
- [Extract number of rows from faceted ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107119/extract-number-of-rows-from-faceted-ggplot) (`gg_facet_nrow()`).

Comment: Sorry, when I run this code, I get the message: "Error: invalid 'width' or 'height'" on the Shiny window. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 8):

If using `facet_wrap` rather than `facet_grid`, the `gg_facet_nrow` function provided by Aurelien callens should be modified to:

```
gg_facet_nrow <- function(p){
    num_panels <- length(unique(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$PANEL)) # get number of panels
    num_rows <- wrap_dims(num_panels)[1] # get number of rows
}
```

If you've defined the number of columns, then the function can be written as follows:

```
gg_facet_nrow <- function(p){
    num_panels <- length(unique(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$PANEL)) # get number of panels
    num_cols <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$facet$params$ncol # get number of columns set by user
    num_rows <- wrap_dims(num_panels, ncol=num_cols)[1] # determine number of rows
}
```

Besides changing to `facet_wrap`, other code provided in Aurelien callens answer remains the same.