# How to increase the size of a plot resulting from grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, gridextra

I am working with R and Shiny to show different tables at once by using the packages ggplot2 and gridExtra.

My problem is that, when I try to use gridExtra to merge 12 plots, they turn out to be tiny.

The code I have for the merging is the following:

```
grid.arrange(p1, p12, p2, p22, p3, p32, p4, p42, p5, p52, p6, p62,
             ncol=2)
```

And this is how all plots are coded:

```
p62 = ggplot(data = dataframe1, aes(x = Week, y = DB, con = Type)) +
  xlab("Week") +
  ggtitle("Country") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "italic")) +
  ylab("DB") +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Type), size = 1) + 
  guides(col = guide_legend(title = "Period")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#999999', '#E69F00', "purple"))
```

When I test it using only 4 plots, the size of the individual plots is perfect:

[image: Plot sizes with only 4 plots]

But when I write all 12, they become tiny:

[image: Plot sizes with all 12 plots]

My question is then: Is there a way to change the size of the individual plots?

Comment: in general: increase the height and width of your output device i.e. `pdf(..., height= , width= )` but for shiny maybe try along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914398/increase-plot-size-in-shiny-when-using-ggplot-facets

Comment: @user20650 I knew there had to be an easy "height=" option I was missing somewhere... Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: You can also remove all legends and keep only 1 to save space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple parts to this answer:

In Shiny, to increase the size (height) or a plot output, use the height argument in the output element in your UI:

```
plotOutput(outputId, height = "400px")
```

Next, as @Tung suggested, you don't have to plot all redundant legends. See `grid_arrange_shared_legend` in the package `lemon`, and perhaps `g_legend`.